# Jquery Autocomplete on input box after click

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to use autocomplete on multiple inputs. All the inputs will show up when I click a button. I am trying to do it using class.
Here is HTML:

```
<div layout = "row" ng-repeat="project in projects">    
    <div layout = "column" layout-align="center center" flex="33">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Project Name</label>
                <input class="autoc" type="text" placeholder="{{project.id}}" ng-keyup="myFunct($event)">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here is my controller code-
On clicking the  button setCity function is being called. It fills the projects array and also jquery code is written inside it.

```
$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.setCity =function(cityname) {
    $scope.projects = [];
    for (var key in $scope.list) {
        if ($scope.list[key].city == cityname.toLowerCase()) {
            $scope.projects.push($scope.list[key]);
        }
    }

    $( ".autoc").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: $scope.items
    });

};
```

The autocomplete is not working on input boxes.
Other suggestions to do this are also welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The elements are added to the DOM dynamically. This might be a problem. Use something more angular than complicating it by jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/swfjT/5205/

Comment: I thought so. I am not able to come up with an alternative to do what I want.

Answer (score -1):

1- you have to take Multiple input in html code as same class

```
    <div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

2 - then use Js Code

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
```